# Is there a "switch" to disable viewport geometry node instances (to reduce lagging in viewport)?

Tags: geometry, geometry-nodes, instances

Just looking for a toggle that would disable geo-nodes instances easily.

I appreciate I can do this manually in the outliner but this would also kill the base geometry in the view. I would just like to disable all scene instances with one click.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the example. You can use **Is Viewport** node to get information that it is a viewport, not render. Then you can pass it to a **switch** node like this:

[image]

When you'll have a switcher to version without instances like this:

[image]